# Requesting Scalar Values from main thread managedobjectcontext from background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have a method that runs in a background thread using a copy of NSManagedObjectContext which is specially generated when the background thread starts as per Apples recommendations.

In this method it makes a call to shared instance of a class, this shared instance is used for managing property values.

The shared instance that managed properties uses a NSManagedObjectContext on the main thread, now even though the background thread method should not use the NSManagedObjectContext on the main thread, it shouldn't really matter if the shared property manager class does or does not use the such a context as it only returns scalar values back to the background thread (at least that's my understanding).

So, why does the shared property class hang when retrieving values via the main threads context when called from the background thread? It doesn't need to pass an NSManagedObject or even update one so I cannot see what difference it would make.

I can appreciate that my approach is probably wrong but I want to understand at a base level why this is. At the moment I cannot understand this whole system enough to be able to think beyond Apples recommended methods of implementation and that's just a black magic approach which I don't like.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does using:

```
[theContext performBlock:^{
    // do stuff on the context's queue, launch asynchronously
}];
```

-- or --

```
[theContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    // do stuff on the context's queue, run synchronously
}];
```

-- *just work* for you? If so, you're done.

If not, take a long, hard look at how your contexts are setup, being passed around, and used. If they all share a root context, you should be able to "move" data between them easily, so long as you lookup any objectIDs always on your current context.

Contexts are bound to threads/queues, basically, so always use a given context as a a reference for where to do work. `performBlock:` is one way to do this.

Comment: I will give this a go and feedback on results soon.